how can i move hamburger menu to right side on maui Windows?
I am making Windows app using maui. I want to move my hamburger button to right side.
this is my appshell.xaml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    xmlns:Pages="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Pages"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
    Title="MauiApp2">

    <FlyoutItem x:Name="Tabs"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Main"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Pages:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Settings" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Pages:SettingsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="About" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Pages:AboutPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>

I used FlowDirection="RightToLeft".
but not working on Windows.


This is a known issue on the github :  How to switch .NET MAUI Flyout of Shell to the right with FlowDirection?.
